# Coin flip experiment with biased coins (and analogy to real-life problem)

Tags: bayesian

In order to determine if a coin is fair by an experiment I flipped it 20 times and received 7 heads. Since the cumulative probability to have 7 or less heads is 13% with a binomial distribution I choose to not reject the null hypothesis if I wanted a 95% significance level.

What would happen if I knew before I started the experiment that I took the coin from a wallet where 80% of the coins were biased towards tails' favour and 20% were neutral? Then I would have to take this into account when calculating the level for significance right?

If the answer to my question is "Yes" then I wonder if this is ever applied in statistical studies? Say for example that I want to test the gender equality on a workplace in a country where women earn 10% less than men for equal work. When I make a suitable test on the salaries of the employees, should I take into account that I know that in general women earn less than men in the workplace's country?

Comment: You are mostly just asking if Bayesian statistics are ever used & the answer is *yes*. Note that that information can also be incorporated into frequentist analyses: You don't have to have Ho: p = .5.

Comment: In the coin flip example it's quite straight forward but is it often used in more complicated situations such as in the gender equality example where the probability of "selecting" an equal-opportunity employer is hard to estimate?

Comment: gender equality question is much more difficult than coin question, which is itself not so trivial as may seem. the reason is that salary differential can be considered a mean only unconditionally, i.e. it doesn't control for any other factors while in your study you probably do to some degree. so, incorporating this average is very difficult

Answer (score 1):

I am going to work this problem from the end to the beginning.

> When I make a suitable test on the salaries of the employees, should I take into account that I know that in general women earn less than men in the workplace's country?

No.  These are not analogous problems.  You are assuming discrimination and you are likely going to land in Yule's paradox.

It is not safe to assume that the wage differences are due to discrimination by sex.

Imagine that you had a country with only three occupations.  Two were white-collar jobs and the other was coal mining.  Coal mining is dangerous.  You would expect high wages.  It is also a field women rarely enter into for a variety of reasons.

You find that the country has a wage difference, however, there is no wage differential by occupation class.  Within each of the three classes, there is no difference in average wages, but when the occupation is not considered there is.

This is an area where the null hypothesis method shines because it does not assume discrimination, it must be shown.  As the null hypothesis method is conservative due to insuring a maximum percentage of false positives, it is also a nice risk-averse tool.

I worked at a place where the female employees were certain that there was wage discrimination.  All salaries were tested by rank and the result was, in all categories, $\bar{x}_{female}>\bar{x}_{male}$.  It is dangerous to assume discrimination.

Now as to your unfair coin problem, it would be problematic to solve.  Presumably, your biased coins are homogenous, but what you are solving is difficult to define.  What is your sample space?

Twenty percent of your sample space would be made up of tosses where $\theta=.5$, but eighty percent of your sample space would be made up of tosses where $0<\theta<.5$.  What would the sample made up of biased coins look like?  Is the bias 50.0001 toward tails or 99.99999 toward tails?

It also cannot be tested on the Bayesian side because the mass at $\theta=.5$ is zero because it has no width.

In 96 occupations in the United States, women make significantly more than men, up to 40% more in some fields.  If you assumed $\theta\le{.5}$ then you would miss that as they would show up as $.5$ because you have put zero mass at $\theta>.5$.  Some of those fields are very high paying, such as software engineering.

Comment: coal mining is a weak example. the wages are not high in this field. also, your saying that it is dangerous that's why men enter it more is considered a problematic reasoning these days. a better example would be to refer to a recent study of heavily union regulated labor contracts, where it was impossible to pay men more than women per hour. it turned out that women chose to work less, in terms of hours charged, and had lower wages. in this case there are no other factors that could be perceived discriminatory, such as gender biased barriers to entry

Comment: @Aksakal you are right.  Wages are down.  They are still high, but not what they were.  I used to live in coal country, but that was before everything fell off a cliff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would have to consider that when calculating your probability, and you would also need to have an idea of how is the bias of your coins...

Assuming that you pick a coin at random you have a 0.2 probability of having a honest coin, and a 0.8 probability of having a tails-biased one. Say that your biased coins will land on heads with probability $p$, and on tails with probability $1-p$. Then, conditioning on what coin you picked:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\text{Probability of having $k$ heads in $n$ flips} &= 0.2*\binom{n}{k} \cfrac{1}{2}^{n} + 0.8*\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}
\end{aligned} $$

So if you have $20$ flips and $7$ of them are heads,

$$ \begin{aligned}
\text{Probability of having $7$ heads in $20$ flips} &= 0.2*77520* \cfrac{1}{2}^{20} + 0.8*77520*p^{7}(1-p)^{20}
 \\
&\approx 0.015 + 62016*p^{7}(1-p)^{20}
\end{aligned} $$

and you can find the cumulative distribution likewise.

The answer for the second part of your question is also yes, you should take that into account and I expect people do that in real life problems. Using conditional probabilities depending on previous knowledge / outcomes is not unusual and it's also sensible. However I think your example with gender equality in salaries is a bit confuse... why would you test if salaries are equal if you already know that women earn 10% less than men in this country?

I would suggest you take a look into conditional probability and Bayesian techniques (priori and posteriori distributions) in case you're not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the gender equality question I assumed that even though the country in general is unequal it is possible for a specific company to have gender equality. What I want to test is if the company is equal or not and my question was whether or not to take the country's inequality into account or not. As I understand your answer that's what I should do!

Comment: Ah I see! It seems then it's really a case of choosing a frequentist test or a bayesian one - so it depends on the way you want to test it really. Bayesian inference takes into account previous knowledge of observed phenomena... so I think that's what you're looking for. If you've never heard of it before, there are plenty of references and textbooks out there... Wikipedia (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) could be a place to start, and I can point some more references later if you're interested (I don't have the names with me right now)

Comment: I am stuck trying to turn this analysis into an actual test. What does one do given that $p$ is *unknown* (as in the question)? How do you compute any probabilities (even under the null hypothesis)?